# how to retrive data from VARRAY and filter it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

i have to retrieve specific data from Varray for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE class_t IS VARRAY(9) OF VARCHAR(5);/   
create table exprement(name VARCHAR2(20), seat class_t);
insert into exprement(name,seat) values('JPZ',class_t('AC1','EC'));
insert into exprement(name,seat) values('ABC',class_t('GEN','EC'));
insert into exprement(name,seat) values('DFG',class_t('AC1','EC'));
```

i want to retrieve the name where VARRAY includes AC1
i tried `select * from exprement where seat='AC1';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   experiment e
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE(e.seat) WHERE COLUMN_VALUE = 'AC1');
```

or

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   experiment e
       CROSS APPLY TABLE (e.seat) s
WHERE  s.COLUMN_VALUE = 'AC1';
```

---

As an aside, if you defined `seat` as a nested table (rather than a `VARRAY`) then you could use the `MEMBER OF` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   experiment
WHERE  'AC1' MEMBER OF seat;
```

But that doesn't work for `VARRAY`s or associative arrays.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=9fe7302e07dc45c3b5bf663c947abfb5)*

Comment: Thanks alot i was able to retrieve all the values from the varray and make a view from that and do operation on that but you solution is much better thanks a lot